# Firestore - appending data to a single value inside a struct

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, struct, google-cloud-firestore

How can I update a single value inside of a struct. Currently I'm fetching all of the data inside multiple documents of a collection with the below function. the data structure is as follows:

- People - collection

  - DocumentID

    - Name: "Joe"
    - Friends (Object)

      - 1 (Object)

        - Name: "Sally"
      - 2 (Object)

        - Name: "Sam"
  - DocumentID

    - Name: "Emily"
    - Friends (Object)

      - 1 (Object)

        - Name: "Peter".

If I run the below code it jut creates a new array, whereas I would like to merge the two together. Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks!!

```
func loadData() {

    let userRef = db.collection("Users").document(user!)

    let docRef = userRef.collection("People")

    docRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
                for document in snapshot.documents {

                    let data = document.data()

                    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""

                    let newPeople = People(name: name, friends: [:])
                    self.peopleArray.append(newPeople)

                    if let friends = data["Friends"] as? [String: Any] {
                        for (key, _) in friends {

                            let number = friends[key] as? [String: Any] ?? [:]

                            let friendsName = number["name"] as? String ?? ""

                            \\ The code in which I want to update the value of friendsName into the previous set array
                            let newFriends = People(name: name, friendsName: friendsName)
                            self.peopleArray.append(newFriends) 
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What I would like the array to look like:**

[    name: Joe, friends: ["name": Sally, "name": Sam]], [name: Emily, friends: [name: Peter]]

**Updated Code**

```
    var friendsName: [String: [String: Int]] = [:]
    var friendsArray = [String: Int]()

    func loadData() {

    let userRef = db.collection("Users").document(user!)

    let docRef = userRef.collection("People")

    docRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
                for document in snapshot.documents {

                    let data = document.data()

                    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""

                    if let friends = data["Friends"] as? [String: Any] {
                        for friend in friends {

                            let key = friend.key
                            let values = friend.value

                            let friendsDict = friends[key] as? [String: Any] ?? [:]

                            let friendsNameString = friendsDict["name"] as? String ?? ""

                            self.friendsArray.updateValue(friendsNameString, forKey: key)

                        }

                        self.friendsName.updateValue(self.friendsArray, forKey: "name")

                        let newPeople = People(name: name, friends: self.friendsName)
                        self.peopleArray.append(newPeople)

                        self.friendsArray.removeAll()

                        self.friendsName.removeAll()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the *DispatchQueue.main.async* as Firebase closure UI elements run on the main thread.

Comment: If you think through it, the Friends child node is actually a snapshot, just like what's returned from the getDocument call and can be iterated over the same way (i.e. for friend in friends.documents) and the child data can be accessed in the same way. Also, there's nothing in the posted code that would *create a new array*, but it's unclear what that means exactly.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks very much for the reply! Very sorry if I was unclear with the question, but with my being fairly new to coding I'm struggling to find the correct solution to my problem. Basically I have a tableview inside of each tableview cell. The outer cell displays the "name" field from the document and each inner cell displays the "name" field from the "friends" object. What I'm wanting to do is get the data from each object inside the documents and append it into the peopleArray in the form of an array. Do you have any suggestions on how I can do this. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Hi Jay, please see the example array below the code, as this I what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: It's clear; iterate over the Friends child node (within each DocumentID node) and add each users Friends to the peopleArray. You're casting the entire Friends node to a dictionary when it could just be iterated over . Consider the Friends node to be a snapshot that can iterated over just like you are iterating over the People node to get each person. So it would be something like *friends = friendsSnap.documents* and then iterate over *friends* to get each friend as a dictionary of a key: value pair of name: persons_name, then create your friend object and add to the array.

Comment: Hi Jay, I'm confused as to where I put "friends = friendsSnap.documents". Do I put it instead of "if let friends = data["Friends"] as? [String: Any] { for (key, _) in friends { " ? What is the correct way of writing it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jay, I have posted my updated code, which is working the way I wanted, however I'm not sure its the correct way to do it. I would like to implement your method but I'm not sure how to. Also do you have any idea how I can load the friends name into each cells label inside a tableviewcell as mentioned before. This part is confusing me too. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it seems a little too complex to what you require. Firestore has quite fast queries so you can have different collections for people and friends.

Lets say for example that in your "people" collection you have the names of all the users and other properties that you may need... Email, age, gender, etc etc.

Then in a second collection you can add the relations for each user. For example, "Friends" contains documents with fields friendA: AAA, FriendB: BBB. Then you won't have any duplicates in your data.

The way you are doing it creates too many duplicated that you don't need. For example, in your Joe document you have set that Sally is a friend. But then in your Sally document you will have to set that Joe is a friend. This makes the database more difficult to maintain and with a lot of duplicates.

If you make two different collections for People and Friends the code for fetching also becomes simpler.